# Order isomorphism between closed intervals of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Does an order isomorphism between any two disjoint closed intervals of real numbers such as $[0,1]$ and $[3,4]$ exist? If it does, is it unique? Is there any way to explicitly specify it?

I am a beginner so the question is probably pretty dumb, I apologize for that.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Simple questions like this, that sounds like someone just copied their homework in the hope somebody else would do it for them, are not popular and tend to get closed. Please improve the question by adding something about your own thoughts on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it always exists:$$\begin{array}{ccc}[a,b]&\longrightarrow&[c,d]\\t&\mapsto&c+\dfrac{d-c}{b-a}(t-a).\end{array}$$And, no, it doesn't have to be unique. Take$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,1]&\longrightarrow&[0,1]\\t&\mapsto&t^2.\end{array}$$